# Difference between BeforeUpload and UploadFile events in plupload

Tags: javascript, file-upload, plupload

What is the difference between [BeforeUpload](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.Uploader.html-BeforeUpload) and [UploadFile](http://www.plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.Uploader.html-UploadFile) events in plupload? Both should be fired just before the file is uploaded. No difference is obvious from the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeforeUpload is triggered before file is uploaded, while UploadFile triggers after upload is already started (for the latter to be true UploadFile should be bound after uploader.init()).

This is from plupload FAQ:

http://www.plupload.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=917

Comment: Seems that you just googled it, right? :) Thanks, good lesson, I should have used google before asking :)

Comment: Yes, that's how I usually find answers :)